# Popup box position restrict to the content area

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've mentioned the code, I'm trying to create a text editor which popups  up just below or above the content editable div area, Problem is if the div tag is close upward margin the popup goes upward, also its not draggable. Please help me in this.

```js
$(function(){
            var mouseX;
            var mouseY;
            var modal = false;
            $(document).mousemove(function(f){
                mouseX = f.pageX;
                mouseY = f.pageY;
            });
            var openPopup = function(e){ //Function to open popup
                $(e).fadeIn(400);
                $('#mask, [data-nitstextpopup]').fadeIn(400).css({'top': mouseY,'left': mouseX}).draggable({ containment: 'body' });
                $('#mask').css({'top': 0, 'left': 0});
                $('[data-nitstextbutton]').hide();
            };
            var closePopup = function() { // Function to close the popup
                    $('#mask, [data-nitstextpopup]').fadeOut(400);
                    $('[data-nitstextbutton]').show();
            };
                
            $('[data-nitspagelabel]').hover(function(){
                $(this).css('border','solid 1px #777');
            }, function(){
                $(this).css('border','none');
            });
            $('[data-nitspagelabel]').click(function(){
                $(this).attr('contenteditable','true');
                var labeltype= $('[data-nitspagelabel]').data("nitslabeltype");
                if(labeltype == "text"){
                    if(modal == false){
                        modal = true;
                        $('[data-nitstextbutton]').css({'top':mouseY, 'left':mouseX}).fadeIn(400).click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            var popupbox = $(this).attr('href');
                            openPopup(popupbox);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#mask').on('click', function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                closePopup();
                modal = false;
                $('[data-nitstextbutton]').hide();
            });
            $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) {
                    closePopup();
                    modal = false;
                    $('[data-nitstextbutton]').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
#mask {
            display: none;
            background: #9ACD32;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            z-index: 88888;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0.2
        }
        [data-nitstextpopup]{
            display: none;
            background: #e2e2e2;
            padding: 0px;
            float: left;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            position: fixed;
            
            width: 250px;
            margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
            z-index: 99999;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-rc.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body>
<div id="mask"></div>
<div>
<h3>this is new html document generated by newject extention</h3>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" data-nitstextbutton style="display: none;">
    <a href="#nitstexteditor" class="btn btn-circle btn-sm default">
        Edit <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-icon-only btn-circle default">
        <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="editable" style ="top: 50%; left: 50%" data-nitspagelabel="1" data-nitslabeltype="text"><h3>This is the content editable where I can change fonts and edit text</h3></div>
<div id="nitstexteditor" style="display: none;" data-nitstextpopup="0" data-nitseditor="1">
    <div class="portlet box blue">
  <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Text Editor
   </div>
            <div class="tools">
    <a href="" class="remove">
    </a>
   </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body form">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left">
           <i class="fa fa-magic"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-circle-right" placeholder="Select style">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left">
                                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-circle-right" placeholder="Select font">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon input-circle-left">
                                <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control input-circle-right" placeholder="Select Size">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-bold"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-italic"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-underline"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-align-right"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-icon-only default">
                            <i class="fa fa-chain-broken"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given extra `margin` on `[data-nitstextpopup]`

Remove `margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;` and add `margin` extact what you need

**UPDATE**

If you want draggable div then use `.draggable();` instead of `.draggable({ containment: 'body' })`

Read More about [jQuery Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)